# ember.js page context with multiple nested routes and hasMany relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I'm brand new to ember.js (started with 3.0) and struggling to achieve what I would expect is a fairly conventional use case without using what seems like unconventional methods or soon to be deprecated features.

The use case in Ember is to display, and paginate, multiple related resources on a parent resources page.

I'm really enjoying using Ember so far but a little exasperated that such a simple use case has been so difficult to overcome. Been ok with the learning curve with everything else so far, but I've hit a wall here.

I have a JSON API backend, with a reasonably complex, (mostly) normalized DB where there are a few key resources and multiple join tables describing the various ways they can relate to each other.

Stripped down setup below:

Models:

```
// app/models/label.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  contactInfo: DS.attr(),
  releases: DS.hasMany('release'),
  artists: DS.hasMany('artist'),
  //...
});

// app/models/artist.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  realname: DS.attr(),
  profile: DS.attr(),
  labels: DS.hasMany('label'),
  //...
});

// app/models/release.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  released: DS.attr(),
  label: DS.belongsTo('label'),
  //...
});
```

Router:

```
  // app/router.js
  //...

  // labels
  this.route('labels', function() {
    this.route('label', {path: '/:id'}, function(){
      this.route('artists');
      this.route('releases');
    });
  });
  // artists
  this.route('artists', function() {
    this.route('show', {path: '/:id'});
  });
  // releases
  this.route('releases', function() {
    this.route('show', {path: '/:id'});
  });
  // ...
```

Routes:

```
// app/routes/labels/label.js
export default Route.extend({
  model(params){
    return this.store.findRecord('label', params.id)
  }
});

// app/routes/labels/label/artists.js
export default Route.extend({
  model(){
    let label = this.modelFor('labels.label')
    return label.query('artists')
  },
});

// app/routes/labels/label/releases.js
export default Route.extend({
  model(){
    let label = this.modelFor('labels.label')
    return label.query('releases')
  },
)};
```

Templates:

```
// app/templates/application.hbs
<h1> Welcome to Ember! </h1>
{{outlet}}

// app/templates/labels/label.js
<h2>{{model.name}}</h2>

<h4>Artists</h4>
// insert sensible way to render artists here

<h4>Releases</h4>
// insert sensible way to render releases here
{{outlet}}
```

**Strategies I've attempted so far:**

1. Calling a labels related `artists` and `releases` directly in the `labels/label` template, ignoring the nested routes for relations and passing the promise into a component, or using `{{render 'labels/label/artists'}}`

This gets the context lazily onto the page, but pagination here was a nightmare. Using the `ember-data-has-many-query` extension I managed to cobble together a controller action for the `labels.label` route:

```
// app/controllers/labels/label.js
export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['artistsPage'],
  artistsPage = 1,
  actions:{
    pageArtists(direction){
      // console.log(direction)
      const label = this.currentModel;
      if(direction == 'forward'){
        let artists = label.query('artists', {page: this.artistsPage+1});
        this.set('artistsPage', this.artistsPage+1);
      }else if (direction == 'back'){
        let artists = label.query('artists', {page: this.artistsPage-1});
        this.set('artistsPage', this.artistsPage-1);
      }

    }
  }
 });
```

This is very broken though in that the route knows nothing about the param being set in the action, so on any page refresh they decouple. I abandoned trying to get the `labels.label` routes model hook to play nicely with the controller params in lieu of another approach:

2. Using nested routes (as shown above) to handle the relations independently of the parent, and load them in individually into the `label` route.

**Status Quo:**

I'm attempting to use named outlets, but haven't been able to get the context onto the page without hitting a single related resources url, eg `/labels/123/artists` or `/labels/123/releases`.

So :

```
  // app/routes/labels/label/artists.js
  // ...
  renderTemplate(){
    this.render({
      'into':'labels/label',
      'outlet':'artists'
    })
  }
```

Will get the context into the named outlet `{{outlet 'artists'}}` in `templates/labels/label`, but I can't repeat this for the `releases` relation because we are at `/labels/123/artists`.

Attempting to set `renderTemplate` in the `labels.label` route, ie:

```
this.render('labels/label/artists',{
  into: 'label/label',
  outlet: 'artists',
  controller: 'labels.label.artists'
})
```

doesn't actually render the route and/or send it to the outlet.

Ultimately I'm hoping to use a pagination approach similar to the one described by Balint Erdi [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPxiiAGMSzE&feature=youtu.be) which implements nested routes and some custom adapter logic to handle the pagination for related resources.

The desired behaviour is for the relationship contexts to be displayed, along with pagination at the url `labels/123`.

I've exhausted looking through the guides, API documentation, discourse forum and here, and still at a loss.

What (assuming multiple things) am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry you're hitting a wall with this! Unfortunately, it's hard to answer this because you've provided too many questions and too much information. I would recommend you split this up into multiple distinct queries, or just come over the the Ember Slack #-help channel and chat with the Ember folks there.

Comment: Understood, was trying to be thorough but clearly went over the top! I'll try the help channel, many thanks for the reply.

Comment: What is this `query` method you are calling in your routes `model()` hook on `DS.Model` resolved by `store.findRecord()`? Concerning documentation `DS.Model` does not have a `query` method.

Comment: @jelhan this was an attempt to get the relations using the addon `ember-data-has-many-query`, which didn't work. In the end after some guidance on #help in the ember slack, I completely abandoned using the subroute / relation approach, updated my backend to pretend it could scope the relations like a belongsTo, so for example `/artists?filter[label_id]=123`, and including these in an `Ember.RSVP.hash`. Still relatively disgruntled that this is the canonical way to solve a basic use case but hey ho, it works.

Comment: Why didn't you use `this.modelFor('labels.label').get('artists');`? If `artists` are not already loaded, ember-data will fetch them depending on available relationship information. If you don't support pagination or backend search / sorting for this related records, ember-data relationship is providing everything you need.

Comment: @jelhan the relations need to paginate, which my jsonapi backend supports, but my understanding is that you can't send query parameters on relations without writing a custom adapter. Am I missing something? Your help is much appreciated!